# spring boot static content

Tags: css, spring, spring-boot

I'm having trouble serving up static content with Spring Boot.

I'm using the default config location(s): `src/main/resources/static/css` and `src/main/resources/static/js`.

When the pages load I get a `404` for all the static content. I even added `permitAll` to my security settings.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
    .authorizeRequests()    
      .antMatchers("/css/**","/js/**").permitAll()
      .antMatchers("/services/**").hasRole("PREAUTH_USER")
      .antMatchers("/", "/dashboard").permitAll()
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
      .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
      .permitAll()
    .and()
      .logout()
      .permitAll();
}
```

My resource handler:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) { 
  registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/");
}
```

...when I hit `login` my CSS is returing a `404`: `http://localhost:8080/login`

Here are the response headers:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/css/preauth.css
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date:Fri, 01 Sep 2017 17:04:59 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
Request Headers
view source
Accept:text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:JSESSIONID=D1399529A7AD61D0FA67ECF0343D3A03
Host:localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/login
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Are you running it as a jar?

Comment: if you are using the default resources folder then there is no need to configure the addresource handler. you can remove it and try again.  SpringBoot will configure static folder and set resources ready to consume

Comment: also visit https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot review how to configure resource handler.

Comment: There should be no need for your manual resource handler configuration. Spring Boot will auto-configure it for you. I wonder if you've unintentionally turned that off by using `@EnableWebMvc`?

Comment: I agree there should be no need for the resource handler. I didn't have it in my original config. I added it because of the 404.. I removed it again and continue to get 404 for my static resources. I also removed @EnableWebMvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be when I extended WebMvcConfigurationSupport in my appConfig class(I needed to configure messageconverters), WebMvcAutoConfiguration is disabled. So I had to add

```
private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
        "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
        "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/" };
```

And

```
   @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/webjars/**")) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations(
            "classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
}
if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/**")) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations(
            CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
}
```

EDIT:
The above code is not required. I changed my config class to extend WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and the above changes are not required..See the comment below from @AndyWilkinson

Comment: Why are you extending `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`? That's a rather unusual thing to do in a Spring Boot application. The recommended approach is to extend `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` instead. That allows you to customise Spring MVC's auto-configuration, while also keeping Spring Boot's defaults.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson, thank Andy you are correct.. I modified my code and everything worked as I originally expected

Comment: `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` is now deprecated